# How to add an AccessLogValve to Tomcat programmatically?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, logging

I'm working on a Spring boot application, and I'd like to route Tomcat's access logs through my slf4j logging system and finally to a remote syslog.

Since it's Spring, I'd like to avoid touching tomcat's server.xml file.

My AccessLogValve is pretty simple:

```
import java.io.CharArrayWriter;
import org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve;

public class Log4JAccessLogValve extends AccessLogValve {
    @Override
    public void log(CharArrayWriter message) {
        log.info(message.toString());
    }
}
```

And I was hoping it would be possible to use something like this to hook it up to Tomcat:

```
@Component
public class LogConfig {

    @Autowired
    private ServletContext servletContext;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setAccessLogValve() {
        ((ApplicationContextFacade)servletContext).addValve(new Log4JAccessLogValve());
    }

}
```

except the addValve() method doesn't exist...

So... anyone have an idea how I can hook in my AccessLogValve?

---

I'm also open to completely different suggestions to get access logs into a remote syslog, but we're making dozens of micro services so it has to be a pretty standardized approach that's simple to implement for each micro service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

combining these answers into something that works with springboot 2.0

```
import org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatServletWebServerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.io.CharArrayWriter;

/**
 * see https://www.baeldung.com/embeddedservletcontainercustomizer-configurableembeddedservletcontainer-spring-boot
 * 
*/
@Component
@Slf4j
public class CustomizeEmbeddedTomcatContainer implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> {

    @Override
    public void customize(TomcatServletWebServerFactory factory) {

        log.info("configuring embedded Tomcat");
        TomcatSlf4jAccessValve accessLogValve = new TomcatSlf4jAccessValve();
        accessLogValve.setEnabled(true);

        /**
         * for pattern format see https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/AccessLogValve.html
         */
        accessLogValve.setPattern("request: method=%m uri=\"%U\" response: statuscode=%s bytes=%b duration=%D(ms) client: remoteip=%a user=%u useragent=\"%{User-Agent}i\"");

        factory.addContextValves(accessLogValve);
    }


    public static class TomcatSlf4jAccessValve extends AbstractAccessLogValve {

        Logger httpAccessLogLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger("http_access_log");

        @Override
        protected void log(CharArrayWriter message) {
            httpAccessLogLogger.info(message.toString());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I've never found a proper answer to this, so I'll give you lead on this question :) I've migrated away from Spring and Tomcat because of neverending bullshit like this :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition, I will recommend extending Log4JAccessLogValve with AbstractAccessLogValve instead of AccessLogValve. It will not initialize file access log file related functionality of the AccessLogValve

For example:

```
import java.io.CharArrayWriter;
import org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve;

public class Log4JAccessLogValve extends AbstractAccessLogValve {

    @Override
    protected void log(CharArrayWriter message) {
        LOGGER.info(message.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer interface.  Add a custom valve to your embedded tomcat.

For example

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

   @Override
   public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
       if (container instanceof TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) {
           TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
           AccessLogValve accessLogValve = new Log4JAccessLogValve();
           accessLogValve.setDirectory("/var/log/access_log");
           accessLogValve.setPattern("%h %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b - %T");
           accessLogValve.setSuffix(".log");
           factory.addContextValves(accessLogValve);
       } else {
           logger.error("WARNING! this customizer does not support a custom configured container");
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: I've now tried a bunch of different versions of this, but my log(CharArrayWriter message) method never runs, according to my profiler... I'm guessing that tomcat isn't running the valve for some reason.

Comment: Is it possible that factory.addContextValves() is adding to something not connected to the actual Tomcat server?

Comment: My own solution will be pretty simple: screw syslog... it's a hack on an outdated system anyway... 

I'm just gonna dump logs to the local filesystem, and set up logstash to collect, centralize and process them. 

I just need to figure out how to get Tomcat to flush it's access log cache every 30 seconds or so, but that's a different matter...

Thanks for your help Johnny, I hope it helps someone else :)