# Apache tomcat 8.5 access log with log4j2

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j2

I try to change `Apache Tomcat 8.5` log by using `log4j2`. I could successfully implement it.

However, there is one log type which I am unable to log with `log4j2`, the `localhost_access_log`

This log was set in the `server.xml` file

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" 
       directory="logs"
       prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
       pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
```

How can I change it so that it will be log by `log4j2` also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in [Tomcat 8.5 Documentation:](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/logging.html#Access_logging)

> Access logging is a related but different feature, which is
>   implemented as a Valve. It uses self-contained logic to write its log
>   files. The essential requirement for access logging is to handle a
>   large continuous stream of data with low overhead, so it only uses
>   Apache Commons Logging for its own debug messages. This implementation
>   approach avoids additional overhead and potentially complex
>   configuration. Please refer to the Valves documentation for more
>   details on its configuration, including the various report formats.

Also check documentation for [Access Log Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Logging)

Thus said - due to the sometimes extreme performance requirements imposed on logging all requests to a tomcat instance without slowing it down (much), these are not meant to be controlled by default logging implementation.

If you *absolutely require* to be able to configure this with log4j2 as well and know what you're doing, you can always create your own Access Log Valve by implementing `org.apache.catalina.AccessLog` and using that in your tomcat configuration.

Comment: There are some implementations given here  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40174290/7748072

Comment: Hi Jan, actually I have solve this issue in another way. The reason i use log4j2 is to roll the file name without date pattern within the file name. After read through document, I found out that renameOnRotate="true" can be set in valve tag. So my issue had been solve =D