# 2 stdout sources - interrupted writing problem

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, kubernetes

We got a couple spring boot applications in k8s that write both application log and tomcat access log to stdout.

When the log throughput is really high (either caused by amount of requests or amount of applciation logs) then it sometimes happens that log lines get interrupted.

In our case this looks like this:

```
[04/Aug/2021:13:39:27 +0200] - "GET /some/api/path?listWithIds=22838de1,e38e2021-08-04 13:39:26.774 ERROR 8 --- [ SomeThread-1] a.b.c.foo.bar.FooBarClass      : Oh no, some error occured
e7fb,cd089756,1b6248ee HTTP/1.1" 200 (1 ms)
```

desired state:

```
[04/Aug/2021:13:39:27 +0200] - "GET /some/api/path?listWithIds=22838de1,e38ee7fb,cd089756,1b6248ee HTTP/1.1" 200 (1 ms)
2021-08-04 13:39:26.774 ERROR 8 --- [ SomeThread-1] a.b.c.foo.bar.FooBarClass      : Oh no, some error occured
```

is there some way to prevent this?
maybe a tomcat, java or spring-boot setting?
or a setting on a container level to make sure that each line is buffered correctly

Comment: You can try disabling buffering in the `AccessLogValve` (cf. [`AccessLogValve` attributes](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve/Attributes)), though it is not a guarantee that all lines will be written atomically. Which logging framework are you using?

Comment: we're using the logging framework that comes with spring boot per default.
i guess slf4j? edit: nvm spring boot apparantly uses logback per default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.out` had better be thread-safe, but that doesn't mean it won't interleave text when multiple threads write to it. Writing both application logs and HTTP server logs to the same stream seems like a mistake to me for at least this reason, but others as well.

If you want to aggregate logs together, using a character stream is *not* the way to do it. Instead, you need to use a logging framework that understands separate log-events which it can write coherently to that aggregate destination.

You may need to write your own `AccessLogValve`subclass which uses your logging framework instead of writing directly to a stream.

Comment: ok i'll try this out and let you know if we got it to work. btw to explain a bit the reason why we are writing both to stdout is that we use fluentd (but switching to vector soon) to process the logs for our k8s pods. fluentd and vector appear to only be able to read from stdout here so if you have more than 1 log then writing them to stdout is a pretty easy approach. but while researching i could find that using a sidecar is also possible https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/logging/#sidecar-container-with-logging-agent

Comment: 5 months later we finally released a version using a custom AccessLogValve to pipe the access log through SLF4J.
I found this answer a while back https://stackoverflow.com/a/58934822/16592542 which pretty much did what we needed (with some minor changes). Thanks for your help!

Comment: If you have written an access-log-to-logging-framework Valve, would you consider donating it to the Apache Tomcat project? If it's general enough, I'm sure they'd accept it and then you don't have to baby-sit that code anymore.

Comment: idk if it's generic enough. just like in the answer I linked I just extend from `AbstractAccessLogValve` and then override the `log` method and use SLF4J's `LoggerFactory` to log the message as info. I had a brief look into the tomcat repo and i dont even know if i could add slf4j as a dependency in there