# How do i catch an HTTP request header parse error thrown by Http11Processor?

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, log4j2, nio

I am running a spring boot application with an embedded Tomcat server on an AWS EC2 instance. I use `Log4J2` to log both the spring boot logs as well as the tomcat server logs.

Tomcat will usually display a log that includes the ip address of the computer that made the request, the endpoint that was requested and how long it took to respond. But this only happens when the application is able to process the request and send a response.

If the request can't be processed because the request header can't be parsed then the `Http11Processor` will throw an error that is logged but that does not include an ip address.

The log looks like this:

> [INFO ] 2022-08-06 22:37:26.363 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] Http11Processor
>
> - Error parsing HTTP request header  Note: further occurrences of HTTP request parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid character found in the
>   request target
>   [/index.php?s=/Index/\think\app/invokefunction&function=call_user_func_array&vars[0]=md5&vars[1][]=HelloThinkPHP21
>   ]. The valid characters are defined in RFC 7230 and RFC 3986
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11InputBuffer.parseRequestLine(Http11InputBuffer.java:494)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:?]
>   at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:271)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:?]
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:?]
>   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:?]
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:?]
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:?]
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:?]
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:?]
>   at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>   ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar!/:?]
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[?:?]

This error was caused by a bot that was scanning my server for `php` related vulnerabilities. I want to block this bot but i need the ip address to do that and `http11Processor` doesn't log that by default.

So i want to catch this exception and log the ip address in the catch clause. My question is: Where should i place this catch clause?

I log the tomcat server logs using a custom `AccessLogValve` that looks like this:

```
public class Log4JAccessValve extends AbstractAccessLogValve { 

    private static final Logger httpAccessLogLogger = LogManager.getLogger("http_access_log");

    @Override //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40172395/how-to-add-an-accesslogvalve-to-tomcat-programmatically
    protected void log(CharArrayWriter message) {
        httpAccessLogLogger.info(message.toString());
    }
}
```

But i don't think the `http11Processor` passed through this `AccessLogValve` or else the log would have mentioned `http_access_log` instead of `http-nio-8080-exec-1`. How do i catch the exceptions coming from `Http11Processor` so that i can alter the error message?

Comment: why not just write a custom filter that logs the ip address?

Comment: I have a custom `@WebFilter` class that does just that, but the `doFilter` method inside this class is never run when `http11Processor` throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a non-recommended but effective way that you can customize a `Valve` and get the `Throwable` with the following code.

```java
Throwable throwable = (Throwable) request.getAttribute(RequestDispatcher.ERROR_EXCEPTION);
```

Refer to `ErrorReportValve` implementation.

Comment: I have a custom `ErrorReportValve` class as well, but the mentioned exception doesn't pass through that class either.